Can't import the named export (COMPONENT) from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
After I tried a refresh reinstall of node_modules in team’s project (I wanted to switch from v18.15.0 to v16.20.2 - NodeJS), when I type npm start, I got like 42 errors like:
Can't import the named export (COMPONENT) from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available).
exemple
Any ideas to solve it? I have to mention that
my teammates can run the project without any error, so I don’t think my problem is related to some piece of code. Something’s wrong with some changes on my laptop.
Thanks!
It was weird that when I used npm install (to install the new version of NodeJS, I had to do it with —-force flag, because I got some warnings like:
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: formik-material-ui@0.0.22
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   46 more (@material-ui/core, react-dom, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from formik-material-ui@0.0.22
npm WARN node_modules/formik-material-ui
npm WARN   formik-material-ui@"0.0.22" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from formik-material-ui@0.0.22
npm WARN   node_modules/formik-material-ui
npm WARN     formik-material-ui@"0.0.22" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-addons-css-transition-group@16.0.0-alpha.3
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

At the end of the logs file, I found:
Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8.0" from formik-material-ui@0.0.22
node_modules/formik-material-ui
  formik-material-ui@"0.0.22" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
node_modules/react
  peer react@"^16.8.0" from formik-material-ui@0.0.22
  node_modules/formik-material-ui
    formik-material-ui@"0.0.22" from the root project 

I get this error…

"Can't import the named export (COMPONENT) from non EcmaScript module " - the question doesn't contain your setup, which the problem is very specific to. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 . You are supposed to remove node_modules but NOT package lock when changing node versions. It looks like you did both, so you could end up with wrong package versions for anything (webpack is only mentioned on a screenshot), these peer dep warnings are only a symptom. It's also possible that node 16 is incompatible with your project. Also NPM versions are not listed.

Thank you! So I need the original package lock?

It would be a good idea to detele & reclone the project and then npm install?

Yes, you need to always keep package lock, unless proven otherwise. Its purpose is to make the set of deps fixed and predictable. Cloning a project shouldn't differ from deleting node_modules and reinstalling deps if working tree is HEAD (and package lock is the same in both). You can try both ways in case it still fails for you

Okay. Thank you! So now I need to delete (again) node_modules, replace package lock with the original one and the npm install?

That's what I'd do in the first place. You may not need to reinstall deps when switching between 16 and 18, this depends on the deps

I tried deleting node_modules and get the original package lock back. It failed. Then i recloned the whole project, used npm install in it and again, failed with the same errors

This means the project doesn't contain proper package lock that resolves correctly dep versions, so you need to use --force. Ask team members to commit lock file if it differs on their side, this allows to get dep versions that are known to work. Any other errors need to be addressed specifically. As I said, it's possible that node 16 is incompatible with your project

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

--legacy-peer-deps: ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.
--strict-peer-deps: fail and abort the install process for any conflicting peerDependencies when encountered. By default, npm will only crash for peerDependencies conflicts caused by the direct dependencies of the root project.
--force: will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
